# Deploy Meteor Application to Heroku Meteor v 1.0.2.1

Tags: git, heroku, meteor

I am following the directions from this [here](http://www.growthux.com/ux-html-css-js-growth-hack/installing-meteor-on-heroku), but in step 6 instead of using:

`--buildpack https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite`

I am using:

`--buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git`

Everything works until I get to step 11:

`git push heroku master`

LOGS:

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.97 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Installing node
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: Downloading Meteor distribution
remote: 
remote: Meteor 1.0.2.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
remote: 
remote: Now you need to do one of the following:
remote: 
remote:   (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
remote:   (2) Run this command as root:
remote:         cp "/tmp/buildpack_b8184dbff0f82703cfc7c7d1179c360e/meteor-    Kgek/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.0.38/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch- meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
remote: 
remote: Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
remote: docs.meteor.com.
remote: -----> Bundling bundle
remote: ios: platform is not in this project
remote: android: platform is not in this project
remote: npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
remote: npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
remote: npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
remote: 
remote: > fibers@1.0.1 install /tmp/build_b8184dbff0f82703cfc7c7d1179c360e/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
remote: > node ./build.js
remote: 
remote: `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
remote: Binary is fine; exiting
remote: underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore
remote: 
remote: semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver
remote: 
remote: eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
remote: └── type-of@2.0.1
remote: 
remote: fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
remote: 
remote: chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
remote: ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.2
remote: ├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
remote: ├── supports-color@0.2.0
remote: ├── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
remote: └── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
remote: 
remote: source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
remote: └── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)
remote: -----> Adding PATH environment
remote: -----> Running extras
remote: -----> Adding MONGOHQ_URL -> MONGO_URL env
remote: -----> Adding MONGOLAB_URI -> MONGO_URL env
remote: -----> Installing phantomjs.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types   -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Node.js -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 22.1MB
remote: -----> Launching... 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failure creating release
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to natetest19.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/natetest19.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/natetest19.git'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue for a while. I tried several different buildpacks but the problem didn't go away.

I ended up fixing my problem, however, by doing the following:

- Delete my heroku project
- Re-clone my git project to a new directory
- Follow all steps from "Create your heroku app" on https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor
- $$$

My suspicion is that there was something stateful in the heroku project that got screwed up from all the buildpack switching.

Also, I should mention that only after re-creating my heroku project did I ever set the `ROOT_URL`, so I suppose that could have been the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
heroku addons:add mongohq:sandbox
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still getting the error: `Adding mongohq:free on testproject... failed
 !    Add-on plan not found.`

Comment: Error: `!That add-on plan is only available to select users.`

Comment: Also, per the README of that buildpack https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite, *You need to have a verified account so the buildpack can add a mongohq:sandbox addon*.

Comment: Per https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite/issues/52, you should either **heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/djhi/heroku-buildpack-meteorite** or try another buildpack **https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse**

Comment: my account is verified through heroku, but I am not using the `buildpack-meteorite`, I am using the `buildpack-horse`

Comment: It's probably worth trying the other buildpack based on that lengthy issue discussion.

Comment: @Nate - Did you try the buildback I suggested. If so, were there any errors?

Comment: I did I tried both `meteorite` and `horse`. Both had the same errors.

Comment: @Nate - can you post the entire results of **heroku logs**, please?

Comment: @ChipCastle please see log in question update. Also I'm not quite sure if i'm executing the git correctly. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Thanks. Did you run **heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=github.com/djhi/heroku-buildpack-meteorite** before pushing?  See the bottom of https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite/issues/52 for info.